# How do I jump to a method in RubyMine?

Tags: rubymine

In Visual Studio, the editor has a drop-down list of functions in the current class; clicking on one will take me to the top of that function.  Is there a way to get a similar behaviour from RubyMine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggested this as a feature request to the folks at JetBrains, and within the day they got back to me to tell me about the 'File Structure Popup' on ^F12 which does very nearly what I want; it's an extra keypress but I can live with it.

Comment: On Windows `Ctrl + F12`

Comment: The caret symbol `^` denotes ctrl.

Answer (score 2):

If you're working on a Rails project, change the project view to Rails (change the View as: dropdown value)

Online help is [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/rails-view.html).

It looks like this is as close as it gets to the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: that's a pity.  It would fit so well in the navigation bar.  Perhaps I should file a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+0 key in editor will show all methods with search capacity. 
The same is drop-down menu Navigate -> File structure.